# Merge multiple arrays of unique occurrences

Tags: arrays, matlab, merge

I want to merge multiple arrays of unique occurrences to a single array. To get the arrays in the first place I use this code, where image series is a slice from a tiff image imported using *imread*:

```
a = unique(img_series);
occu = [a,histc(img_series(:),a)];
```

I do that multiple times, because the tiff image I'm using has multiple hundred images stacked, which my RAM will not support to import at once. So each 'occu' looks something like this (first number is the unique value, second number is the number of occurrences):

```
occu1      occu2    .....
0   1      1   2
12  1      10  1
14  1      12  1
15  1      14  2
..  ..     ..  ..    .....
```

Now I want to merge them all together, or better merge them in each iteration, when I'm reading another stacked image.

The merged results should be a 2D matrix similar to the one above. The number of occurrences of the same values should be added to one another, as this is the whole point of counting them. So the result of the above example should be this:

```
occu_total
0   1
1   2
10  1
12  2
14  3
15  1 
..  ..
```

I found the `join` command, but that one does not seem to work here. I guess I could do it the long way of searching the matching number and add the occurrences together and so on, but there must be a quicker way of doing it.

Comment: How do you want to merge them? As a 3D matrix, as a 2D matrix appending columns or as a 2D matrix appending rows?

Comment: As a 2D matrix, increasing the count of occurences. So for the example above: [ 0 1; 1 2; 10 1; 12 2; 14 2; 15 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = [0 1;12 1; 14 1;15 1];B = [1 2;10 1;12 1;14 2];
tmp = [A;B]; %// merge arrays into a single one
tmp(:,1) = tmp(:,1)+1;%// remove zero occurrences by adding 1 to everything
C = accumarray(tmp(:,1),tmp(:,2)); %// add occurrences all up
D = [1:numel(C)].'; %// create numbered array
E = [D C];
E((C==0),:)=[]; %// get output
E(:,1) = E(:,1)-1;%// subtract the 1 again

E =
     0     1
     1     2
    10     1
    12     2
    14     3
    15     1
```

Job for [`accumarray`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). This takes the first argument as your dictionary key, and adds the values of the each key together. The addition and subtraction of `1` is done because `0` cannot be an index in MATLAB. To circumvent this (assuming you have no negative numbers), you can simply add 1 and remove that afterwards, shifting all your indices to positive integers. If you hit negative numbers, subtract `tmp(:,1) = min(tmp(:,1)+1` and add `E(:,1) = min(tmp(:,1)-1`

Comment: They do not have the same number of rows, as shown in the above example the occurring values can be different.

Comment: Using your code the matrices will simply be concatenated. I have edited my question to explain what the result should be. I'm counting occurrences of unique values, so each value in the first column of the resulting matrix can only appear once and they all need to be in the correct order. The second value needs to be the SUM of the occurrences of the temporary matrices.

Comment: C = [63 15], is not what I'm looking for. I edited my question again to make clear what the result of merging should be.

Comment: Swap the indices in the `accumarray` in that case, I'll update it.

Comment: Now we're pretty close, thanks. I guess there's a type, the E should be a D. However I don't get the same array as you do when I run the code in Matlab, there's a line of code missing maybe?

Comment: I guess your last edit took some time to appear here, refreshed multiple times. Now it's there. Thank you for your help :)